# Como concatenar dois componentes React?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tenho a sequinte função, que não funciona.

```
textao() {
 var texto =  <Text>Texto1</Text>;
 var texto2 = <Text>Texto2</Text>;
 return texto + texto2;
}
```

Quero concatenar dois componentes. Sei que poderia fazer assim:

```
textao() {
 var texto =  <View><Text>Texto1</Text><Text>Texto2</Text></View>;
 return texto;
}
```

Mas pretendo fazer laços e funções recursivas. Existe alguma forma de concatenar dois componentes? Ou então alguma função do tipo `append` que faz um componento inserir outro dentro?

Pensei em fazer assim:

```
concatena(c1, c2) {
  return <View>{c1}{c2}</View>
}
```

Mas achei força a barra demais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi vc não quer concatenar componentes (o que não é possível fazer em React), vc precisa exibir um componente após o outro de forma dinâmica, certo?

Vc pode colocar os componentes dentro de um array e em seguida iterar sob ele.

```js
const textao = () {
 var Texto = <Text>Texto1</Text>;
 var Texto2 = <Text>Texto2</Text>;
 return [Texto, Texto2];
}


const ComponentExample = () => (
  <View>
    {
      textao.map(value => (
        value
      ))
    }
  </View>
)
```